# SLR or Polynomial Regression

Tags: python, regression

I am studying Regression analysis in Python right now. I want to ask what (and why) would provide me accurate results in Python  if I do a regression analysis for the following scatter-plot variables: SLR or Polynomial Regression [image: Scatter-plot for Highway-mpg(independent variable) and Price(dependent variable)]

Comment: Do you have multiple independent variables? or just a couple?

Comment: Just a couple. 1 independent and 1 dependent variable.

Comment: Then, use SLR if is for something simple. since you dont have more variables.

Answer (score 0):

What I assume you are asking is whether to perform basis expansion (adding poylnomial terms) to increase model performance / decrease bias, right? You can do this anyway together with L2-regularized regression, which is the machine learning approach. This selects the best model for you with cross-validation.

In classical statistics, the approach would be to try different models by removing or adding variables (e.g. an x^(-1) term) and to compute the F-scores, read more here about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems.

Comment: You might be correct with your explanation but I want a simple answer for my question. Let me ask my question in a simple way. If I have 2 variable columns lets say "Mileage of cars"[Independent variable] and "Price of cars"[Dependent variable] and I have to make a model to determine the "price" of a car on the basis of the "mileage" it gives. I believe I can do that only when I regress the data using regression tools like SLR or Polynomial Regression. My question is that how do I determine which tool should I use for regression: SLR or Polynomial?